# After stopping Apache service, why can I still get Apache default page on my IP address?

Tags: linux, nginx, apache2

I want to install Nginx, but the port 80 has been taken up by Apache2. I stop it by:

```
$ sudo kill -9 my-apache-pid

$ sudo service apache2 stop

$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
[ ok ] Stopping apache2 (via systemctl): apache2.service.
```

and I can install Nginx. I use`sudo systemctl status nginx`.
It shows working well and Apache2 seems inactive. But when I enter my IP address in the browser, it still shows Apache2 hello-page. Why?

Comment: Nginx might be running, but showing you the `index.html` that came with apache. Try `ls -l /var/www/html`, you might have both `index.html` left over from Apache, and `index.nginx-debian.html`.

Comment: try in incognito window to check if it's cache or the apache is still running

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. To my wonder clearing history and cookies of the browser worked.

Answer (score 1):

Apache and Nginx home pages located in this directory:

```
/var/www/html
```

But there is a small point, and that is that each of these two apps that were installed earlier takes up the `index.html` file, and when you enter the address of `localhost` in the browser, that file actually opens.

As a result, all you have to do is go into this directory and see what the name of Nginx home file.you must do this in your terminal:

```
ls -l /var/www/html
```

that show `index.nginx-debian.html` name for Nginx html file, So if you search for this address in your browser:

```
localhost/index.nginx-debian.html
```

you can see the home page of Nginx.

**all you need for show Nginx home page when search `localhost` is change then name of those two files.**

Answer (score 0):

Even after you remove apache2 completely, you will still have its "default site" files sitting in /var/www/

Run the following command and refresh the page.

```
mv /var/www/html/index.html index.html_bkp
```